# Change structure JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following structure, response of my webservice:

```
{"rows":[
    {"1","A Time to Kill", "John Grisham", "100"},
    {"2","A Time to Kill", "John Grisham", "200"},
    {"3","A Time to Kill", "John Grisham", "500"}
]}
```

I need change the structure with the next one:

```
{rows:[
         { id:1, data: ["A Time to Kill", "John Grisham", "100"]},
         { id:2, data: ["Blood and Smoke", "Stephen King", "1000"]},
         { id:3, data: ["The Rainmaker", "John Grisham", "-200"]}
]
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you get the missing values from?

Comment: No relationship shown to map the first to the second

Comment: In this case, id_documento will be the id

Comment: And data? @AlvaroMaravi

Comment: "Nombre_Documento" and their values

Comment: @Azim i've changed the original json with the columns desired.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid json. Where are the keys to the objects in the array?

Comment: `{"1","A Time to Kill", "John Grisham", "100"}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: You probably meant`["1","A Time to Kill", "John Grisham", "100"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use other keys then the old ones and build a new object with the wanted structure.

```js
var data = { rows: [{ Id_Tipo_Documento: "1", Nombre_Documento: "Dni" }, { Id_Tipo_Documento: "2", Nombre_Documento: "Carnet de Extranjería" }, { Id_Tipo_Documento: "3", Nombre_Documento: "Pasaporte" }] },
    result = {
        rows: data.rows.map(
            ({ Id_Tipo_Documento, Nombre_Documento }) => ({ id: Id_Tipo_Documento, data: [Nombre_Documento] })
        )
    };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```